# How do I load a HTML page as WordPress Homepage without adding it in the 'Pages' section

Tags: html, homepage

So I understand that it is possible to load a HTML page on WordPress by adding a folder with the HTML, CSS and js in the root directory. However, the HTML page only loads on domain.com/foldername, if I had added all the files in a folder named 'foldername'.

If I wanted the home page to load from the HTML file - that is load the HTML page on domain.com directly, how would I go about it?